# What's CScript Error: Can't find script engine "JScript" for script?

Tags: android, eclipse, command-line, cordova, jscript

I get `CScript Error: Can't find script engine "JScript" for script` for a .js file while i'm trying to create a project on PhoneGap , does anyone know what does that mean and how can I fix it and make the Android project successfully?
Thanks

Comment: Are you developing in Windows?  Microsoft has two programs in Windows, `cscript.exe` and `wscript.exe`, that execute scripts in VB or Javascript.  You might have the .js file extension associated with cscript.

Comment: @Big Ed , Yes I do on Windows, well what shall I do then?

Comment: Try right-clicking on a .js file and choosing "Open With..." from the menu.  Choose your text editor of choice and make sure the "Always use this file" box is checked.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you run the command line tool with your ordinary user. Try to run it as Administrator (right click on the icon and choose "Run as Administrator").
I did the same and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the .js file class data is missing or incorrect. See http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/230/1/Error-There-is-no-script-engine-for-file-extension-when-running-js-files.html for solution.